# How to add a time to given columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with several columns. The odd columns contain the time series, the even columns the data:

```
time1.in.s <- seq(0.010, 100, length.out = 100)
time2.in.s <- seq(0.022, 100, length.out = 100)
data1 <- seq(-10, 100, length.out = 100)
data2 <- seq(-25, 80, length.out = 100)

my.df <- data.frame(time1.in.s, data1, time2.in.s, data2)
```

(In real life, I have more columns).

Now the time is the odd columns is relative, in seconds.

I want to add a given start time to all the time values:

```
start.time <- strptime("2016-11-22_15-44-24",
                       format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S",
                       tz = "UTC")
```

I know how to select the odd columns:

```
odd.indexes <- seq(1, ncol(my.df), 2)
```

But to add the start time to the relative times, I did something naïve...

```
my.df[, odd.indexes] <- start.time + my.df[, odd.indexes]
```

... which doesn't work:

> Error in start.time + my.df[, odd.indexes] :
>   non-numeric argument
>   to binary operator
>
> In addition: Warning message: Incompatible methods
>   ("+.POSIXt", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to loop over the columns and then do the `+`

```
my.df[, odd.indexes] <- lapply(my.df[, odd.indexes], `+`, start.time)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should also work (slight modification of what you are doing):

```
my.df[, odd.indexes] <- as.data.frame(start.time + as.matrix(my.df[, odd.indexes]))
```